# Complexity of Brute Force Knapsack Problem?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I was wondering if someone could confirm my working for the complexity for 0/1 Knapsack Brute Force,

I reasoned it is $O(N\cdot2^N)$

This is because to work out all possible subsets (The way I did brute force was to compute power set then calc weight/values for each set), takes $2^N$ and then we calculate the sum of each subset of size from 1 to $N$, that takes $N\cdot2^N$.

Space complexity would be $O(2^N)$ for the total number of subsets.

But from my notes the Brute Force 0/1 Knapsack is $O(2^N)$ with space $O(N)$.

I think that is for the recursive solution but my brute force is not recursive, so is my complexity correct ?

Comment: why do you even need more space? power sets could be enumerated? then given an integer you can calculate which items are in, and what is the weight of the set?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I just want to know if computing the power set and using it in the 0/1 Knapsack the way I have gives the complexities I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the next is the input of the problem:

- A set of non-negative numbers $\{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\}$ - weights
- A set of numbers $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ - values
- A non-negative value $W$ - available volume

We want to solve something like
$$\max\limits_{i} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i v_i$$
$$\text{s.t.}\quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i w_i \leq W$$

There are exactly $2^n$ subsets, and in the trivial solution we will check them all!

For $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 2^n-1\}$ look at the binary representation of $i$ and take the objects accordingly, i.e. if bit $b_{j-1}$ (counted from right to left) at position $j-1$ is set ($=1$) take the object $j$ to your bag. If the total weight of the subset $i$ (i.e. all the taken objects) weighs less than $W$, record the weight of the subset. If it is less than previous record - update the record. You can forget the weight now !!!

E.g. for $i = 134_{10} = 10000110_2$ you take objects indexed by $2,3, 8$ to the subset and do not take anything else.